# Finding the dimensions of the the right circular cylinder of greatest volume

Tags: calculus, volume

Find the dimensions of the the right circular cylinder of greatest volume
that can be inscribed in a given right circular cone with radius $b$ and
height $a$.  [The figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6KW6.png)

I have tried to do $V=\pi r^2h$ but how to make $V$ a function of one variable using the cone dimensions?

Answer (score 2):

Hint...use similar triangles $$\frac{a-h}{r}=\frac ab$$ to eliminate either $r$ or $h$ so you have a function of one variable.